# Error when extending the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::class

Tags: magento2, blocks, extend

I tried to extend the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::class` like this :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
        array $data = []
    ) { 
        parent::__construct($context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
        $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml');
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        $collection->setVisibility(array(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH ,
            ));

        $select = $collection->getSelect();
            $fromPart = $select->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM);
            if (isset($fromPart['price_index']['joinType'])){
                $fromPart['price_index']['joinType'] = 'left join';
                $select->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM, $fromPart);
            }

        $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        if (!$collection->isLoaded()) {
            $collection->load();
        }

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

But i always got an error like this:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid
>   method
>   Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor::addToolbarBlock

I already deleted the generated/code & generated/metadata, clear the cache, run :

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` class `addToolbarBlock()` is private function so you can not use this in your new file here `Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

You can create new private function in your extended file like below.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
        array $data = []
    ) { 
        parent::__construct($context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
        $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml');
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        $collection->setVisibility(array(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH ,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH ,
            ));

        $select = $collection->getSelect();
            $fromPart = $select->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM);
            if (isset($fromPart['price_index']['joinType'])){
                $fromPart['price_index']['joinType'] = 'left join';
                $select->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM, $fromPart);
            }

        $this->_addToolbarBlock($collection);

        if (!$collection->isLoaded()) {
            $collection->load();
        }

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Add toolbar block from product listing layout
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    private function _addToolbarBlock(Collection $collection)
    {
        $toolbarLayout = $this->_getToolbarFromLayout();

        if ($toolbarLayout) {
            $this->configureToolbar($toolbarLayout, $collection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get toolbar block from layout
     *
     * @return bool|Toolbar
     */
    private function _getToolbarFromLayout()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();

        $toolbarLayout = false;

        if ($blockName) {
            $toolbarLayout = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        }

        return $toolbarLayout;
    }
}
```

Replace above code in your file and run below command.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope this will help you!